# How to make disappear a button in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I'm trying to hide a button on a form with the following code:

```
$('#ButtonID').hide(); 
document.getElementById('ButtonID').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

But the button is still show in form. I need to know how to make it disappear?

Comment: Your code is completely fine. The problem must be somewhere else. Can you give some more examples? Can you provide a fiddle or at least show how your HTML look like.

Answer (score 1):

you must specify whether you want to hide it or completely remove it from the flow. when you hide it, it still occupies its position and it just simply is hidden but when you set **display:none** it will be removed from page.

this is true

```
document.getElementById('ButtonID').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

but it works on some browsers you must use this as well

```
document.getElementById('ButtonID').setAttribute("style","visibility:hidden");
```

Answer (score 1):

check this out

http://jsfiddle.net/JPmhs/

**JavaScript code should be**

```
document.getElementById("toggle").style.visibility="hidden";
```

HTML

```
<form id="formvisiblity">
    <input id="toggle" type="submit" text="submit" name="accept"/>
</form>
```

**To toggle when clicked**

onclick="function()" attribute will toggle on click

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want `$('#ButtonID').remove();`

Comment: Thanks Rob. But, if i remove then the button onClick function does not work. Actually i need to disappear the button and the control is maintained from remote's up-down button. So there's no need to show it on screen.

Answer (score 0):

```
use the following jquery code:
----------
$("#toggle").attr("style","display:none");


JavaScript use following code:    
----------
document.getElementById("toggle").style.display="none";
```